# Connecting to Google NGrams Data in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I'm trying to connect to the Google NGrams dataset on AWS in EMR. (https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/google-books-ngrams/) However, when I try and load the data using pig, I get a lot of error messages and no real data, likely because the file in the S3 bucket referenced in the above link is encoded. Is there a way to directly access it from pig and apply the proper conversions to make it accessible?

I've tried loading the data, then using limit to try and dump the the first few rows, however I got several errors and a lot of random characters and boxes.

These are the commands I've tried to load the data:

```
trigrams = LOAD 's3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-us-all/3gram/data' AS (trigram:chararray, year:int, occurrences:float, pages:float, books:float);

out = LIMIT trigrams 10;
```

I expected to get the data output in the below format

```
n-gram TAB year TAB occurrences TAB pages TAB books
```

however, all I get are the following error messages and I'm not able to analyze the data.

```
268988 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState  - Pig features used in the script: LIMIT
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO pigstats.ScriptState: Pig features used in the script: LIMIT
269024 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend  - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO data.SchemaTupleBackend: Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
269047 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer  - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer: {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
269103 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager  - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO util.SpillableMemoryManager: Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO output.DirectFileOutputCommitter: Direct Write: DISABLED
269186 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend  - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
19/09/04 01:48:04 INFO data.SchemaTupleBackend: Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
269242 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend  - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
19/09/04 01:48:05 WARN data.SchemaTupleBackend: SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
269245 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage  - Using PigTextInputFormat
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO builtin.PigStorage: Using PigTextInputFormat
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
269252 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths to process : 1
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO util.MapRedUtil: Total input paths to process : 1
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 7e6c862e89bc8db32c064454a55af74ddff73bae]
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-us-all/3gram/data' for reading
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt__0001_m_000001_1' to hdfs://ip-172-31-24-80.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/temp1150533356/tmp1066986243/_temporary/0/task__0001_m_000001
269523 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend  - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
19/09/04 01:48:05 WARN data.SchemaTupleBackend: SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
269531 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths to process : 1
19/09/04 01:48:05 INFO util.MapRedUtil: Total input paths to process : 1
(SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text#com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec�+Gz2rF?��n`�m�������+Gz2rF?��n`�m�֎~� ��|y��hx�������,,,,)
(�
  �
�,,,,)
(��������������▒▒���� �!�"�#�$�%�&�'�(�)�*�+�,�-�.�/�0�1�2�3�4�5�6�7�8�9�:�;�<�=�>�?�@�A�B�C�D�E�F�G�H�I�J�K�L�M�N�O�P�Q�R�S�T�U�V�W�X�Y�Z�[�\�]�^�_�`�a�b�c�d�e�f�g�h�i�j�k�l�m�n�o�p�q�r�s�t�u�v�w�x�y�z�{�|�}�~����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������!�!��������������������������������������������������������������A���������������������������������������������������������������a������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������"�@��������������������������������������������������������������B���������������������������������������������������������������b������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������#�@��������������������������������������������������������������C���������������������������������������������������������������c������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������$�@��������������������������������������������������������������D���������������������������������������������������������������d������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������%�@��������������������������������������������������������������E���������������������������������������������������������������e������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������&�@��������������������������������������������������������������F���������������������������������������������������������������f������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������'�@��������������������������������������������������������������G���������������������������������������������������������������g�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������(��������������������������������H��������������������������������h���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
(��,,,,)
```

Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Input file is in a sequence file format.
Default Pig loader is PigStorage() which is text based. 
If it's a straight forward sequence file with no custom Writable objects, using SequenceFileLoader might work.

```
DEFINE SequenceFileLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader();
...
trigrams = LOAD 's3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-us-all/3gram/data' using SequenceFileLoader AS (trigram:chararray, year:int, occurrences:float, pages:float, books:float);
...
```